# set alias to read variable and then use in second command; only works when I execute them manually

Tags: shell-script, alias, read, postgresql

I am with CentOS 7 and I want to bind an alias to launch PostgreSQL shell(psql). I defined this alias and append it in `/etc/profile.d/alias`:

```
alias psql-local="read -p \"PSQL: enter the DB to connect: \" db ; sudo -i -u postgres psql --dbname $db"
```

It is executable by `root`.

And, I login as `root`, and run `alias`, I get:

```
alias psql-local='read -p "PSQL: enter the DB to connect: " db ; sudo -i -u postgres psql --dbname '
```

**Note here `$db` at the end is empty.**

Then I run `psql-local`, but I get error:

```
[root@lucas_vm ~]
> psql-local
PSQL: enter the DB to connect: jfps
psql: option '--dbname' requires an argument
Try "psql --help" for more information.
```

Then I enter `/etc/profile.d/`, and run `alias.sh` manually, then suddenly I can use this alias:

```
[root@lucas_vm /etc/profile.d]
> . alias.sh
[root@lucas_vm /etc/profile.d]
> psql-local
PSQL: enter the DB to connect: jfps
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

jfps=#
```

If I exit `psql` and run `alias` again, I see this line changed:

```
alias psql-local='read -p "PSQL: enter the DB to connect: " db ; sudo -i -u postgres psql --dbname jfps'
```

Note `$db` is changed to `jfps`.

Then, I try to access another database, and it works again.

But, when I exit and `alias`, I see the `--dbname jfps`, not the name of second database. When I `echo $db`, it, instead, is the name of the second db.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using double-quotes (`"..."`), the `$db` variable will be expanded when you define the alias, not when it's used. Try this instead:

```
alias psql-local='read -p "PSQL: enter the DB to connect: " db ; sudo -i -u postgres psql --dbname "$db"'
```

Comment: Um.. it improves: when login and `alias`, I see: `alias psql-local='read -p \"PSQL: enter the DB to connect: \" db ; sudo -i -u postgres psql --dbname "$db"'`, but when I use it, I see error: `> psql-local \n
"PSQL:jfps \n
-bash: read: \`connect:': not a valid identifier \n
psql: option '--dbname' requires an argument \n
Try "psql --help" for more information.
`
Seems the script is truncated due to single quotes.

Comment: I also tried: 1) single quote `$db`; 2) escape `"` and double quote `$db` 3) double quote `$db` without escaping. But no avail.

Comment: try prepending  a `printf "{%s} " ` before `sudo ...` and tell me the output you're getting.

Comment: OK so I changed back to your solution (single quote all) and add what you said, and I got same error as before, but with extra `{}`. Seems empty `{%s}`.

Comment: Ah I login with remote shell. Does that affect? I tried on the real machine and it is still the same. Seems no impact.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. I've put the `printf` in the answer; it should print something like `{sudo} {-i} {-u} {postgres} {psql} {--dbname} {db you entered}`. What does it give you instead?

Comment: OK I thought it should be separated with `sudo` by period comma. OK I changed as you answered, and login again, and `psql-local` again, I get: `{sudo} {-i} {-u} {postgres} {psql} {--dbname} {jfps} [root@lucas_vm ~]`. Note the pstring is changed to the same line too, but not a big deal

Comment: Oh! now it works. I shouldn't escape and quote the `read` command message.

Comment: Any material easy to understand for variable expansion in shell? Just cannot get it...

Comment: The best thing is to use `set -x` and the `printf "{%s} " ...` trick when in doubt. Anyways, variables (`$x`) and other `$` expansions are performed inside double quotes (`"..."`) but not inside single quotes (`'...'`).